# How do I designate the location of a library in order for a "using" statement to work (C#)

Tags: c#, using

I'm used C# -some- but not recently.

I've got this header from some code, and it calls a custom non-system library, (Dynastream.Fit, at the bottom), but I need to know how to tell the program where it resides so it can compile.  Pretty sure the library is in the SDK I downloaded, just need to find it.  This is the FitSDK from ANT+.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Dynastream.Fit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the dll of `Dynastream.Fit` to your project `Reference` folder by right clicking the reference folder -> add reference -> Browse -> choose the dll; unless you have already installed the assembly in GAC.